# Can't Change bootstrap background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't for the life of me figure out why my I can't get the background to change color or image. I can't see what's preventing the background color from showing when everything looks to be correct in my css.

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- META -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Boots2</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <!-- Slidebar -->
        <link href="css/slidebars.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Slidebar -->
        <link href="css/slidebar-theme.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <div class="sb-navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse sb-slide" role="navigation">
            <!-- Left Control -->
            <div class="sb-toggle-left navbar-left">
                <div class="navicon-line"></div>
                <div class="navicon-line"></div>
                <div class="navicon-line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Boots2</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#about">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Dropdown
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Another action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="top-arrow" href="#top">^</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar -->
        <!-- Site -->
        <div id="sb-site">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Test Page</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, quas delectus aut ipsum tenetur repudiandae fugiat consequuntur modi incidunt quisquam impedit et architecto laboriosam ratione doloribus sit illum maxime at?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, magnam, corrupti, tenetur eum sapiente voluptas necessitatibus tempora velit assumenda veritatis beatae dolorem eos hic voluptatibus cum repellat amet optio officia?</p>
            </div>
            <!-- end container -->
        </div>
        <!-- end sb-site -->
        <!-- Slidebar -->
        <div class="sb-slidebar sb-left sb-style-push">
            <nav>
                <ul class="sb-menu">
                    <li>
                        <img src="#">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Download</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Usage</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">API</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Compatibility</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="sb-toggle-submenu">
                            Help &amp; Issues
                            <span class="sb-caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sb-submenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Overview</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Fixed Positions</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Modal.js</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Squashed Navbar Content</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="#">Github</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <small>Site &copy; 2014 Max Campos</small>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- end Slidebar -->
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Slidebars -->
        <script src="js/slidebars.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function ($) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    // Initiate Slidebars
                    $.slidebars();
                    // Slidebars Submenus
                    $('.sb-toggle-submenu').off('click').on('click', function () {
                        $submenu = $(this).parent().children('.sb-submenu');
                        $(this).add($submenu).toggleClass('sb-submenu-active');
                        // Toggle active class.
                        if ($submenu.hasClass('sb-submenu-active')) {
                            $submenu.slideDown(200);
                        }
                        else {
                            $submenu.slideUp(200);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }) (jQuery);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```css
body {
    background-color: blue;
    padding-top: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
.theme-dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #f2f2f2;
}
.theme-showcase > p > .btn {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
#top-arrow {
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Did you clear your browser's cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be that the CSS for the plugin you are using is over-riding your CSS in main.css. From the Slidebars Github Page:

```
#sb-site, .sb-site-container {
/* You may now use class .sb-site-container instead of #sb-site and use your own id.   However please make sure you don't set any of the following styles any differently on your id. */
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; /* Site sits above Slidebars */
    background-color: #ffffff; /* Default background colour, overwrite this with your own css. I suggest moving your html or body background styling here. Making this transparent will allow the Slidebars beneath to be visible. */
}
```

As you can see, `#sb-site` (which is where your test content sits) has a default background-color of white. You could change the CSS for `#sb-site` in your main.css file to blue to fix your problem.

The browser gives preference to more specific CSS rules, the id `#sb-site` is more specific than the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just put all your body-content inside a wrapper-div. And then set the background-color of the wrapper to the color you want.

Answer (score 0):

While using !important can force your style to be applied, it's generally considered a last resort because it can lead to specificity issues and make your CSS harder to maintain. Try to avoid using !important if possible.

```cs
body {
   background-color: #fff !important;
}
```